# Getting MediaEntryModule as null while fetching RSS feeds. Unable to fetch media content

Tags: java, rss

I am getting MediaEntryModule as null. Because of that i am  unable to fetch Media content like Image, previewImage,Video,audio details.

While debugging i found the Module implementation in SyndEntry is using the following:

DCModuleImpl.interface=interface com.sun.syndication.feed.module.DCModule
DCModuleImpl.uri=http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/

MediaEntryModule mediaModule = (MediaEntryModule) entry.getModule(MediaEntryModule.URI);
mediaModule is coming as null.

Jars used in the java 6 code are.

rome-1.0.jar
rome-modules-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
The only way to read the rss feeds if not getting through rome API is. You need to get the ulr of that feed news as shown below:

```
com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry entry = //get from RSS Url using rome api
String link=entry.getLink();
URL res = new URL(url);
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

URL res = new URL(url);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

```
        URL res = new URL(url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Element head = doc.head();
        Elements titleTags = head.getElementsByTag("title");
        if (!titleTags.isEmpty()) {
        title = titleTags.text();
    } else {
        Elements metaTitle = head.select("meta[property=og:title]");
        title = metaTitle.attr("content");
        if (metaTitle.isEmpty()) {
            Elements metaTitle = head.select("meta[name=twitter:title]");
            title = metaTitle.attr("content");
        }
    }

    String description = "";
    Elements metaDescription = head.select("meta[name=description]");
    if (!metaDescription.isEmpty()) {
        description = metaDescription.attr("content");
    } else {
        Elements metaDescription = head.select("meta[property=og:description]");
        if (!metaDescriptionFacebook.isEmpty()) {
            description = metaDescriptionFacebook.attr("content");
        } else {
            metaDescription = head.select("meta[name=twitter:description]");
            description = metaDescription.attr("content");
        }
    }   
    return description;

    String previewUrl = "";
    Elements metaImage = head.select("link[rel=image_src]");
    if (!metaImage.isEmpty()) {
        previewUrl = metaImage.first().absUrl("href");
    } else {
        Elements metaImage= head.select("meta[property=og:image]");
        if (!metaImageFacebook.isEmpty() && StringUtils.isNotBlank(metaImage.attr("content"))) {
            previewUrl = metaImage.first().absUrl("content");
        } else {
            Elements metaImage = head.select("meta[name=twitter:image]");
            if (!metaImage.isEmpty() && StringUtils.isNotBlank(metaImage.attr("content"))) {
                previewUrl = metaImage.first().absUrl("content");
            }
        }
    }
```

You can get more content like video, audio,etc from Doc element.